# Escaping a string being inserted into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I have tried all combinations of single quotes, double quotes etc but the following code keeps erroring with sql syntax error. The en and cy are paragraphs of text. I think I must be missing something obvious but I cant see it. Any suggestions?

```
$insert_dana = mysql_query("UPDATE Contributor (Summary_en,Summary_cy) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($insert[en][0]) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($insert[cy][0]) . "') WHERE id='$insert[id]'");
```

Comment: post that exact syntax error please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed `insert` and `update` statement syntax. Use this one

```
$insert_dana = mysql_query("UPDATE Contributor set Summary_en = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($insert[en][0]) . "', Summary_cy = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($insert[cy][0]) . "' WHERE id='$insert[id]'");
```

Answer (score 1):

you're confusing [the UPDATE-](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) and [the INSERT-](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)syntax. for `UPDATE`, it's like:

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  field = 'value'
WHERE
  ...
```

while an `INSERT` looks like:

```
INSERT INTO
  table
  (field) 
VALUES
  ('value')
```

you can't write an `UPDATE` with `(field) VALUES ('value')`-syntax.

Comment: Yep im a muppet, the query was originally an Insert so I just changed a bit of it. Bit rusty, not been at it for over 12 months. Thanks